# Finding a Root of a Function Through Bisection

Tags: matlab, math, equation, bisection

I am just learning MATLAB and I am having some issues with finding the roots of this function.

[image: The Function]

Where v0 = 36m/s, t = 4, g = 9.8m/s^2, and Cd = 0.25kg/m. The interval is from [100, 200] with a precision of 10^(-4)

Based on my function, did I input my equation correctly. In addition, is this the correct way to find the roots without using fzero? When I run it, the results don't match up. My instructor said I should be close to a root in less than 20 attempts. Thanks.

```
clear all; close all;

xr = 200; % right boundary
xl = 100; % left boundary

tries = 0;

for j = 1:1000
    xc = (xl + xr)/2;
    fc = sqrt((xc*9.8)/0.25)* tanh(sqrt((0.25 * 9.8) / xc) * 4) - 36;

    if fc>0
        xl = xc;
        tries = tries + 1;
    else
        xr = xc;
        tries = tries + 1;
    end

    if abs(fc)< 10^(-4)
        break
    end
end

tries % record number of attempts
xc % value of root
fc % value of function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **almost** have it correct.  The bisection method requires that you need to check the sign of `f(xl)f(xc)`.  You are only checking for `f(xc)`.  As such, you just need to modify your code with two lines:

1. Add one line to compute `f(xl)`
2. Modify your `if` statement to check the sign of `f(xl)f(xc)`.

Therefore, modifying your code, we get:

```
clear all; close all;

xr = 200; % right boundary
xl = 100; % left boundary

tries = 0;

for j = 1:1000
    xc = (xl + xr)/2;
    fc = sqrt((xc*9.8)/0.25)* tanh(sqrt((0.25 * 9.8) / xc) * 4) - 36;
    %// NEW
    fl = sqrt((xl*9.8)/0.25)* tanh(sqrt((0.25 * 9.8) / xl) * 4) - 36;

    if fl*fc>0 %// CHANGE
        xl = xc;
        tries = tries + 1;
    else
        xr = xc;
        tries = tries + 1;
    end

    if abs(fc)< 10^(-4)
        break
    end
end
```

When I run this code, I get my root to be `xc = 144.4092` and it converges in 12 (`j = 12`) iterations.  I can verify this root with the symbolic mathematics toolbox:

```
%// Make equation and solve for xc
syms xc;
fc = sqrt((xc*9.8)/0.25)* tanh(sqrt((0.25 * 9.8) / xc) * 4) == 36;
solve(fc)

ans =

144.40669396088800683910326198619
```

There are some precision differences after the 2nd decimal place, which makes sense as you are checking to see if the root output is less than 10<sup>-4</sup> and not 0 itself.